# Contact form error dose not send email

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

i am facing a problem in contact form it gets validated successfully and i get the Jquery response " your email has been sent successfully" but the problem is the email dosen't get delivered. i am pasting the code here please help me. its an html based site but.

CONTACT FORM.HTML

```
<!-- contact-area start -->
<div class="contact-area ptb-120 bg-2">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <div class="contact-wrap">
                    <h3>CONTACT INFO</h3>
                    <p>#123 King , Melbourne vic 3000, Sydney New City, Australia</p>
                    <p>(+08) 9673 123 765,(+08) 9673 148 112</p>
                    <p>hello@university.com</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                <div class="contact-form">
                    <div class="cf-msg"></div>
                    <form action="mail.php" method="post" id="cf">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="fname" name="fname">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" name="subject">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <textarea class="contact-textarea" placeholder="Message" id="msg" 
    name="msg"></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                            <button id="submit" class="cont-submit btn-contact" name="submit">Submit 
    A Message</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

MAIL.PHP

```
    <?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    //Taking all values
    $to         = "shijumax@gmail.com";
    $fname      = $_POST['fname'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $subject    = $_POST['subject'];
    $msg        = $_POST['msg'];
    $output     = "Name: ".$fname."\n\nSubject: ".$subject."\n\nMessage: 
    ".$msg;
    $headers    = 'FROM: "'.$email.'"';
    $send       = mail($to, $fname, $output."\n\n***This message has been 
     sent from me", $headers);
    $body = "Name: ".$fname."\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $msg";
    echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
    mail($to, $subject, $body);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You're passing wrong information to variable $header. check php email doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php for example, i think you should remove header and try again. example: mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);

Comment: the mail do gets delivered but it gets into spam of my gmail account showing unknown sender..    $headers    = 'FROM: " '.$email.' " ';    i really need to fetch the senders email from the contact form is their any way i can make it to land in inbox ?

Comment: use SMTP to send mail

Comment: it started working after doing the below modification and successfully emails are getting delivered to inbox and not in spam.                            
    $headers = 'From: "'.$email.'"' . "\r\n" .
              'Reply-To: web@priyaimmigration.com' . "\r\n" .
              'Bcc: shijumax@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
       'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();                             
             mail('web@mmigration.com', $subject, $body, $headers);

Comment: I'm happy it work.

Comment: thanks oyewole thank u very much